# SQL Server 2005 Bitwise Which Day is next?

Tags: sql, datetime, bit-manipulation

I have a table called Jobs that keeps track of jobs and their next run time.  One particular scheduling options allows a job to run several times per week. I use bitwise comparisons to discern which day comes next (Well... I'm trying to anyway.) So for example. I have a table like this..

```
JobID    NextRunTime     DaysOfWeek
  1      12-26-2011         21
```

My bitwise enumeration is like this..

```
Monday = 1
Tuesday = 2
Wednesday = 4
Thursday = 8
Friday = 16
Saturday = 32
Sunday = 64.
```

So we know that this job should run on Monday, Wednesday, Friday. (12-26-2011) is a Monday, so when it updates, it should run again on 12-28-2011 but I am unable to come up with an algorithm that allows me to do programmatically set the new NextRunTime.

This is the method I'm currently trying to get to work with some pseudo-code for what I'm having problems with..

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DaysSchedule') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DaysSchedule
CREATE TABLE #DaysSchedule
(
Monday int, Tuesday Int, Wednesday Int, Thursday INT, Friday INT, Saturday INT, Sunday INT
 )
INSERT INTO #DaysSchedule (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday)
Values(21 & 1,21 & 2,21 & 4,21 & 8,21 & 16 ,21 & 32,21 & 64)
```

This gives us a table that looks like this:

```
Monday    Tuesday    Wednesday    Thursday    Friday    Saturday    Sunday
  1         0           4            0         16          0          0
```

From here the (half) pseudo-code is easy.

```
for (int i=1; i<7, i++)
{
   thisDay = DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(day, i, nextRunTime))  -- we add one day
   if (column named thisDay contains a value > 0) -- if that days value > 0
     begin
        We add the difference of thisDay to NextRunTime to NextRunTime and we're done.
     end
 }
```

Comment: How is this more efficient than just have a `CHAR(7)` with letters for each day you want to run, and `N` for days you don't?  I.e. `MNWNFNN`, then just doing a `PATINDEX()` check for the letter.  In my experience `Bitwise` is cool but overly complicated for about 99% of what is gets used for.

Comment: @JNK Very similar to my original idea. I originally used numerical values for each day.. 135 was (monday, wednesday, friday), 24 (tuesday, thursday), but my boss wants Bitwise and well.. He's the boss. :)

Comment: I can understand that, just bear in mind the boss isn't always right and sometimes they appreciate it when you keep them from embarrassing themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:**  I'm not going to comment on the idea of representing multiple items of data in a single field.  It may or may not be appropriate in this case, I'm just commenting on how to make this type of idea work.

The problem that you are facing is that the information does not actually closely match its use.

At present...
- Extract the DAY from NextRunTime
- Identify the BIT representing that day
- SEARCH for the next bit set to one, cycling around to the start if necessary
- Identify the distance traveled in that search
- Add that distance to NextRunTime

It's just not efficient or simple.

I would recommend instead recording the number of days to add to reach the next planned date.

Examples:

```
-----15 = Saturday and Sunday Only  
1111111 = Every Day  
11113-- = Every Weekday  
2-2-3-- = Monday, Wednesday, Friday
```

This changes the algorithm to...
- Extract the DAY from NextRunTime
- Identify the character in that position
- Cast it to an INT
- Add that many days to NextRunTime

This avoids a search and count section, replacing it with a straight look-up.

It does allow 'dead-ends', or more complex plans.  This may be an advantage or dis-advantage depending on your situation...

```
1111100 = Every weekday for a week, then stop
2222222 = Every other day, on a two week cycle
```

Comment: This is good stuff. But I'm using a Frequency (day, week, month), and a frequencyGap (iterations of the frequency every 1 week, 5 months, 2 days, etc to simply add those to the next run time. And even this is similar to the char(7) idea, which of course is easier, but when it comes down to it isn't as efficient as passing a maximum 127 bitwise value. Plus those don't let me figure out how to make this one work! lol Thanks. :)

Comment: @Kulingar - Sorry, I'm not sure I understand you.  Your original question does not provide the scope for patterns that are different from week to week.  (The binary example can't, for example, plan `every other day` or plan `every 5 months`.)  Can you supply examples of the planning requirements that you need?  From my understanding the proposed solution here provides all functionality that the binary solution can, but with a lookup instead of a search and count...

Comment: You're right. I purposefully excluded those examples because they're done.  It's easy to do a simple DATEADD(Frequency, FrequencyGap, NextRunTime) assuming the next run time occurs on a consistent x number of days, or day of the week, or DATE of the month...

Comment: @Kulingar - I'm still lost as to how this poses you issues then?  Forgive me if I can't see the obvious...  If you have a solution for those case, do you mean that...  Your binary method (or the alternative I propose here) does not need to deal with those cases? (In which case this works, as it does everything your binary method can, but quicker and easier, which I thought was your question.)  Or do you need to adapt you binary method to ALSO deal with your frequency gap requirement?  [`Monday, Wednesday, Friday` example added to show this does what your binary example attempted to do.]

Comment: @Kulingar - Do you mean that CHAR(7) is less efficient than SMALLINT because it uses more disk space?  This is correct, but also note that the SMALLINT version will be massively less efficient in terms of CPU resources due to the requirement to implement a search.  Compressing you information into the smallest space does not yield efficient databases, it yields smaller databases...  (You could store you DB in a zip file and ask the OS to decompress it ever time you need to access it...)

Comment: Yes, this binary method does not deal with the other schedule...  There are two individual scheduling situations, Every X (days, weeks, months), or a week specific schedule (M, W, F), (T,Th, Sat) etc.  The first scheduling situation is unrelated to this method.  Also, about your second post. Disk Space and even Server speed are 'cheap' so IMHO our prime concern is bandwidth or throughput.

Comment: @Kulingar - As the values of DaysOfWeek are unlikely to be transferred over the network very often (How often do you really insert of update these values?) I would suggest that this case is unlikely to have a realistically noticeable effect.  Also, at present, you don't actually have manageable way of interpreting the binary representation.  As for "server speed" being cheap?  The search and count method could be orders of magnitude slower than a look-up method.  I can only strongly urge you to consider an alternative to your binary method, and wish you success in you endeavour :)

Answer (score 1):

Would it be so bad to use three rows to model the three days? e.g.

```
INSERT INTO Jobs (JobID, NextRunTime, RepeatOption)
   VALUES (1, '2011-12-26', 'Y');


INSERT INTO RepeatJobs (JobID, RepeatOption, DaysOffset)
   VALUES (1, 'Y', 2), 
          (1, 'Y', 4);
```

---

If you must go with bitwise, how about creating a lookup table e.g.

```
VALUES (1, 'Monday'), 
       (2, 'Tuesday'), 
       (3, 'Monday'), 
       (3, 'Tuesday'), 
       (4, 'Wednesday'), 
       (5, 'Monday'), 
       (5, 'Wednesday'), 
       (6, 'Tuesday'), 
       (6, 'Wednesday'),        
       (7, 'Monday'), 
       (7, 'Tuesday'), 
       (7, 'Wednesday'), 
       (8, 'Thursday'), 
       (9, 'Monday'), 
       (9, 'Thursday'), 
       (10, 'Tuesday'), 
       (10, 'Thursday'), 
       (11, ...
```

...but rather than 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' etc store the offset in days from a set day of the week, say Sunday, then round down your `NextRunTime` to the Sunday then add the offset etc.

Comment: This would certainly work (though even more difficult that JNK's comment) but this would add some extra, unneeded junk to the data model.

Comment: @Kulingar - this would be a very easy option to expand though...suppose they wanted to add special cases for holidays and such?

Comment: This still has an issue...  How to quickly and easily identify which will be the NEXT day in the schedule?  An more importantly, how many days that means you need to add to the current value in `NextRunTime`?